# Como comparar un ID de una tabla con un ID de $_SESSION? (Restringir comentarios)

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario en el que un usuario escribe un comentario y este se envía a la misma pagina y el comentario aparece uno debajo de otro (**Todo bien**, prácticamente el trabajo ya esta hecho y es el de la siguiente imagen).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que sucede es que estoy tratando de **restringir** que si **El usuario ya escribió un comentario YA NO PUEDA ESCRIBIR OTRA VEZ** (Esto para evitar SPAM).

Se me ocurrió entonces crear  una tabla llamada **comentario_nes** y guardar lo siguiente:
**|ID|IDsuario|IDJuego|Comentarios|**

La tabla se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te fijas en el **código** Se aprecia que el **IDUsuario es igual** a la variable de sesión **$_SESSION['ID']** que es con la que **el usuario logueado se encuentra navegando**.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: **Como puedo comparar la variable *$_SESSION['ID']* con el campo *IDUsuario* para que si ya existe un comentario con IDUsuario la persona no pueda comentar otra vez?**

(Lo eh intentado con isset y con un IF pero no logro conseguirlo, alguna idea? Gracias.

```
               $_GET['id'];


            if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
                echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";


                /* Si se presiona ENVIAR recogo lo que se ENVIO*/
                if (isset($_GET['comentario'])) {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO comentarios_nes(IDUsuario,IDJuego,Comentario) VALUES ('$_SESSION[ID]','$_GET[id]','$_GET[comentario]')";

                    //$sql = "UPDATE  contenidones SET IdComentarios = '$_GET[comentario]' WHERE ID = '$_GET[id]' "; 


                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


                    if ($resultado == true) {
                        echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";
                        echo "Tu comentario se a enviado, gracias";
                        echo "</div>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";
                        echo "El comentario no pudo enviarse trata mas tarde";
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                }
                /* ---*/



                /* Aqui consulto una tabla COMENTARIOSNES */
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM comentarios_nes WHERE IDJuego = '$_GET[id]'";
                $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                $datos = [];
                while ($hileras = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)) {
                    $datos[] = $hileras;
                }
                /* ---*/



                /* Esto es el FORMULARIO*/
                if (isset($_SESSION['ID'])) {
                } else {
                    echo   "<form>";
                    echo       "<div class='form-group'>";
                    echo           "<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Deja un comentario' name='comentario'> ";
                    echo            "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$_GET[id]'>";
                    echo           "<small id='emailHelp' class='form-text text-muted'>Comentario de no mas de 150 caracteres</small>";
                    echo      "</div>";
                    echo       "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'  >Enviar</button>";
                    echo      "</form>";
                }

                /* ---*/

                /* Pinto los COMENTARIOS*/
                foreach ($datos as $i) {
                    echo       "<div  class='bg-light mt-2' ><img src='/Imagenes/Iconos/icono_reporte.png' width=20 height=20> $i[IDUsuario]$i[Comentario]</div>";
                }
                echo       "</div>";
                /* ---*/
            } else {
                echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";
                echo "<p class=''>Inicia sesion para acceder a esta sección</p>";
                echo       "</div>";
            }
```

/////////////

Imagenes con UNIQUE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

/////////Ultima imagen donde parece funcionar lo que cita masterguru

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si creas un índice UNIQUE en la tabla que comprenda los dos campos evitarás que puedan hacerlo.  (ya se que no es la solución a tu pregunta, pero es un parche de mientras arreglas tu problema con el PHP)

Comment: masterguru explícate a que te refieres con UNIQUE (¿Es una sentencia SQL? )

Comment: Míralo aqui:  [enlace](https://www.anerbarrena.com/mysql-create-index-5281/)   estoy hablando de índices de tabla de base de datos.

Comment: masterguru no me ah funcionado... El formulario sigue enviando el mensaje y simplemente cambia el registro del |IDUsuario| por otro numero pero no EVITA que se envié el mensaje...

Comment: Será que tienes esa columna **IDUsuario** como clave primaria y además autoincremental... ¿puede ser?  Otra solución es borrar ese indice y sencillamente establecer esos dos campos como primarios a la vez, sin autoincrementos de ningun tipo.  El efecto sería el mismo, es decir, impedirian que se agregara el dato si se repiten los valores de ambos campos en otro registro previo.

Comment: ¿Pero a cuales 2 índices te refieres? Yo solo hablo del campo **IDUsuario** , no es incrementable ni nada. Cuando envió un comentario con el UNIQUE puesto me lo regresa como "2" y ya no como "1" y puedes seguir insertando registros

Comment: ¿te has leido el enlace que te he pasado antes?  ¿que has hecho para establecer el índice UNIQUE en la tabla?  Enseñame lo que has puesto para ver en que te has equivocado.

Comment: @masterguru acabo de actualizar 2 imagenes de donde agregue el UNIQUE al campo pero aún asi sigues pudiendo enviar el formulario

Comment: Vale, ya veo, el error se debe a que no has creado un índice con las dos columnas (IDUsuario y IDJuegos), sino solo con una.  Pulsa sobre el lapiz **Editar** de ese índice que has creado y agrégale la columna IDJuegos también, y ya está.  Es probable que si ya tienes registros duplicados no te deje o que quizás te diga que se van a borrar registros duplicados.  Si no te deja coges y los borras primero, y luego intentas de nuevo agregar IDJuegos al índice.  Si te deja pero va a borrar registros, pues bueno, que lo haga, y solo te dejará uno.

Comment: @masterguru Ocurrio algo muy extraño (La verdad...). Hice lo que dijiste; Agregue 2 **UNIQUE** uno a **|IDUsuario|** y otro a **|IDJuego|** Entonces con el mismo usuario que estaba logueado no me permitia escribir 2 comentarios (Bien...) Pero cuando me hice una **Segunda cuenta** (Ojo pero no relevante; Me salió un error que repare, nada que ver) Ojo; **No podía insertar comentario** porque ya existía 1 comentario del usuario anterior...

Entonces volví a quitar el UNIQUE del campo IDJuego y ya quedo funcionando. ¿Qué sucede? Pues no lo se... (No se si esta resuelto. ¿Por qué ya si antes no?

Comment: No dije que crearas **DOS** índices UNIQUE... sino uno **COMPUESTO con los dos campos**, y además te expliqué lo que debias hacer para editar y aprovechar el que ya tenias (que has llamado IDUsuario).

Comment: @masterguru Deja ver si entiendo: Me decias que agregara 1 **UNIQUE** al campo **|IDUsuario|** y que lo (Esto no entiendo) ¿"Hiciera compuesto con el **IDJuego**"?

Quiza lo hice sin darme cuenta (Al final a quedado exactamente como la ultima imagen que te envie...) Solo que ahora sin querer de la nada "Ya esta funcionando"...

Debo revisar bien lo que me dices de **"Compuesto"**

Comment: Los índices pueden ser de una columna, de dos columnas, de tres columnas, etc... Asegúrate que el índice que tienes es de **dos** columnas, y que son IDUsuario y IDJuego, y que su tipo de índice es UNIQUE.   Más claro no te lo puedo decir creo.

Comment: A ver si me explico, porque quizás el que se equivoca soy yo... Estoy intentando que los usuarios **no** puedan hacer más de un comentario **por juego**, y de ahí que quiero que crees ese índice **compuesto de dos columnas**.  Si lo que quieres es otra cosa entonces error mio de comprensión y te he mareado para nada.

Comment: @masterguru Eh subido una última imagen, creo que era a lo que te referías (Al final quedo así...) En efecto **Ya esta funcionando** Aunque como dijiste parece mas una especie de "**Hack**" Lo menciono porque también tengo que hacer algo parecido con un boton de "Me gusta" y no se si el concepto me sirva pero por ahora parece servir...

Comment: Si, bueno, es para asegurarte que hagan lo que hagan, y escribas lo que escribas en tu código PHP (bien o mal), no puedan agregar más de un comentario **por juego** gracias al índice que acabas de crear.  Lo del **Me gusta** supongo que será más de lo mismo, pero piensa siempre si el índice debe ser compuesto o simple en cada tabla que lo necesites.  En este caso yo entendí que lo querías así, aunque repasando tu pregunta luego he tenido mis dudas pues no lo has dicho explicitamente, pero me parecía lo lógico.